# Download icon gone in Safari after update

Tags: safari

I updated to Safari Version 13.0.4 on my Mac, but now my downloads icon is gone from my toolbar. There ARE items in the downloads folder, so that is not the problem. In fact, I just downloaded a couple things to see.

I have tried to customize the toolbar, but Downloads is not in there as an option.

Any ideas how to get this back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Downloads icon disappears when you clear out the downloaded items from the list. To make sure it stays quasi-permanently, go to Safari Preferences > General > Remove History items and set it to `Manually`.

This way, as long as you keep at least *one* item in the list of downloads, the icon will stay in the toolbar. Setting it to `Manually` ensures that the other settings - `After one day|one week|two weeks|one month|one year` - will not clear out the list without user intervention.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I already did this, that's why I pointed out that there ARE downloads in my folder and new downloads didn't bring the icon back...I'm sorry I didn't make this clear.

Comment: It not that there are still downloaded files in ~/Downloads, it is the list Safari keeps of downloads that's important. What setting do you have for the `Remove History` preference? If it is already set to `Manual`, set it to another value, close preferences, quit Safari, open Safari, then change the preference back to `Manual`. In my experience, preference file settings can get munged up sometimes, and by setting an expected parameter to some other value, then back, will sometimes force a re-write of the parameter to the value you expect.

Comment: THANK YOU!! I close down Safari and rebooted my computer a couple times and it wasn’t there, but then I downloaded another item and it appeared! LOL thank you so much! I really appreciate you!!

Comment: Yes! It worked! When I shut down safari I lost this page and so I couldn’t find it to tell you that. But I got an email finally so I could get on here. Thank you so much